# Using contentEditable in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a form that will be spans or divs with `contenteditable='true'` I have the following jQuery working to create hidden form fields for all the `.formField` selectors but would like to know if this is the best way to do it or if there is a more efficient way to do it.  The idea is to simply submit the page by standard means and not use ajax. Thanks!

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        $('.formField').each(function(){
            $('<input>').attr({
                type : 'hidden',
                id : $(this).attr('id'),
                name : $(this).attr('name'),
                value : $(this).html() 
            }).appendTo('form');
        })
    })
})
</script>
<form name = "contentEditableTest" id = "contentEditableTest" method = "post">
    <span id = "test" name = "test" contentEditable="true" class = "formField">This is editable</span>
    <span id = "test2" name = "test2" contentEditable="true" class = "formField">This is editable too</span>
    <input type = "submit" id ="submitIt" name="submitIt" value = "go"/>
</form>
```

Comment: use text area - style it to look like a para - code for it to [auto-resize](http://www.impressivewebs.com/textarea-auto-resize/) :)

Comment: In my opinion contentEditable is indicated to fields that need advanced content format, as a e-mail, a stackoverflow question and others.

Comment: @ClaudioSantos yeah, after playing with this a while I'm thinking it may not be the best solution for this particular problem...